# What's an efficient way to transform a two dimensional array of labels to a map from label to coordinates?

Tags: arrays, iterator, rust

The following code works but does multiple passes over the entire array, which I would like to avoid.  Another alternative would have been to sort the `named_coords` array by name and then gather the `pieces` while iterating through the sorted array, but I didn't find a clean way to make that work.  Ideally the answer would use standard adapters and such to transform the collection as a whole.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let p = [ ['I', 'P', 'P', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'V', 'V', 'V']
            , ['I', 'P', 'P', 'X', 'Y', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'V']
            , ['I', 'P', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'F', 'Z', 'Z', 'L', 'V']
            , ['I', 'T', 'W', 'X', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'Z', 'U', 'U']
            , ['I', 'T', 'W', 'W', 'N', 'N', 'F', 'Z', 'Z', 'U']
            , ['T', 'T', 'T', 'W', 'W', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'U', 'U']
            ];

    // Gather named coordinates into a Vec
    let mut named_coords = Vec::new();

    for (n0, j0) in p.iter().enumerate() {
        for (n1, j1) in j0.iter().enumerate() {
            named_coords.push(((n0, n1), *j1));
        }
    }

    // Transform the named coordinates into Vector of names.
    let mut names = named_coords.iter().map(|x| x.1).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    names.sort();
    names.dedup();

    // Filter the named coordinates by name and collect results.
    // Inefficient - iterates over entire named_coords vector multiple times.
    let mut pieces = HashMap::new();
    for name in names {
        pieces.insert(name, named_coords.iter().filter(|&p| p.1 == name).map(|p| p.0).collect::<Vec<_>>());
    }

    // Print out results.
    for n in pieces.iter() {
        for coord in n.1.iter() {
            println!("{} {} {}", n.0, coord.0, coord.1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) API:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let p = [['I', 'P', 'P', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'V', 'V', 'V'],
             ['I', 'P', 'P', 'X', 'Y', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'V'],
             ['I', 'P', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'F', 'Z', 'Z', 'L', 'V'],
             ['I', 'T', 'W', 'X', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'Z', 'U', 'U'],
             ['I', 'T', 'W', 'W', 'N', 'N', 'F', 'Z', 'Z', 'U'],
             ['T', 'T', 'T', 'W', 'W', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'U', 'U']];

    let mut pieces = HashMap::new();
    for (n0, j0) in p.iter().enumerate() {
        for (n1, j1) in j0.iter().enumerate() {
            pieces.entry(j1).or_insert_with(Vec::new).push((n0, n1));
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", pieces);
}
```

Efficient: A single pass through the data and a single hash lookup per item.

Simple: beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: This is the same thing I came up with. Benchmark shows it's 1.7x faster.